# New to Coding, how do I combine several print statements into one nicer looking one?

Tags: printing

Hi I am new to coding was wondering a simple question, how do I combine this piece of code:

```
print("Hi, this program is used for the voting system of the new boat name of Ratentango.")
print()
print("The 4 choices for names are:")
print("Boatie Mac Boatface")
print("Bouyonce")
print("Pride of Ratentango")
print("Black Pearl")
print()
print("Please make sure you enter the correct name, as it is case sensitive and any spelling errors will not be counted.")
print()
```

If not the whole thing, I was thinking just this bit could be combined somehow.

```
print("The 4 choices for names are:")
print("Boatie Mac Boatface")
print("Bouyonce")
print("Pride of Ratentango")
print("Black Pearl")
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are writing in python, please specify your language to the next questions.
For the answer, you can concentrate the string / variables with , sign between them in the print function call.
Example:
Print ('Hello', 'World','!')
Output : Hello World !

If you want to break line after every sentence you sould add \n in the end of each sentence.

Good luck!